# UISegmented Control Inner view should call API after view has been shown

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a '`UISegmentedControl`' which is programatically added in the view controller named `SegmentControllForRides`. (i added UISegmentedControl programatically because segment items will be changed some time 2 or 3.`UISegmentedControl` have three items. items names are ["Request","Upcoming", "Past"]. Each segment will show a `viewController.view` and hide the others. Each view controller have an API call. My problem is when first the `SegmentControllForRides` shows it calls the all three (child) viewcontroller API's( i think because views are hidden but loaded in controller thats why API calls goes to server). Each view controller has a `UITableView` and in `UITableViewCell` there is a `UICollectionView`. I tried to call (again) API when view is shown, in that case API call goes but `UICollectionView` got messed. It shows data of the other cell. For this i tried to

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   reloadCollectionView()
}
```

but this does not help.
I want to call API when child view is shown (not on the `SegmentControllForRides` load). It is also necessary because first controller API response have the effect of the second controller API call. So Kindly guide me how to call API after the view shown.
I will try provide any further detail.
Here is my class.

```
import UIKit

class SegmentControllForRides: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - Variables
    var controller: UIViewController!
    var requestedRideViewController: RequestedRideViewController!
    var upcomingRideViewController: UpcomingRideViewController!
    var myRideViewControllerUpcoming: UIViewController!
    var myRideViewControllerPast: UIViewController!
    var segmentControll: UISegmentedControl!
    var sideMenuOpen = false

    // MARK: - Outlets

    // MARK: - Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        configure()
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if sideMenuOpen {
            openCloseSideMenu()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Actions & Events
    @IBAction func segmentControllChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: User.isAppUsingAsPassenger) {
            switch segmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                print("segment 1")
                myRideViewControllerUpcoming.view.isHidden = false
                myRideViewControllerUpcoming.didMove(toParent: self)
                myRideViewControllerPast.view.isHidden = true
            case 1:
                print("segment 2")
                myRideViewControllerUpcoming.view.isHidden = true
                myRideViewControllerPast.view.isHidden = false
                myRideViewControllerPast.didMove(toParent: self)
            default:
                break
            }
        } else {
            switch segmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                print("segment 1")
                requestedRideViewController.view.isHidden = false
                requestedRideViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
                upcomingRideViewController.view.isHidden = true
                myRideViewControllerPast.view.isHidden = true
            case 1:
                print("segment 2")
                requestedRideViewController.view.isHidden = true
                upcomingRideViewController.view.isHidden = false
//                upcomingRideViewController.getUpcomingRide()
                upcomingRideViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
                myRideViewControllerPast.view.isHidden = true
//                let myClass : UpcomingRideViewController = self.children[1] as! UpcomingRideViewController
//                myClass.myRideTableView.reloadData()
//                myClass.getUpcomingRide()
//                myClass.viewWillAppear(false)
            case 2:
                print("Segment 3")
                requestedRideViewController.view.isHidden = true
                upcomingRideViewController.view.isHidden = true
                myRideViewControllerPast.view.isHidden = false
                myRideViewControllerPast.didMove(toParent: self)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sideMenuClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        openCloseSideMenu()
    }
    @objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        if gesture.direction == .right {
            print("Swipe Right")
            if !sideMenuOpen {
                openCloseSideMenu()
            }
        } else if gesture.direction == .left {
            print("Swipe Left")
            if sideMenuOpen {
                openCloseSideMenu()
            }
        }
    }
    // MARK: - Helper Methods
    private func configure() {
        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
        swipeRight.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
        controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuViewController")

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: User.isAppUsingAsPassenger) {
            let segmentItems = ["Upcoming", "Past"]
            segmentControll = UISegmentedControl(items: segmentItems)
            segmentControll.frame = CGRect(x:0 ,y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 30)
            segmentControll.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentControllChanged), for: .valueChanged)
            segmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
            segmentControll.backgroundColor = .rideelyGray
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                segmentControll.selectedSegmentTintColor = .rideelyYellow
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
            view.addSubview(segmentControll)
            myRideViewControllerUpcoming  = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyRideViewController")
            addChild(myRideViewControllerUpcoming)
            myRideViewControllerUpcoming.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 30)  // or, better, turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and then define constraints for this subview
            view.addSubview(myRideViewControllerUpcoming.view)
            myRideViewControllerUpcoming.didMove(toParent: self)
            myRideViewControllerUpcoming.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0 - self.view.frame.width, y: 30, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 30)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.myRideViewControllerUpcoming.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 30)
            }, completion:nil)
            myRideViewControllerUpcoming.view.isHidden = false

            myRideViewControllerPast  = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyRideViewController")
            addChild(myRideViewControllerPast)
            myRideViewControllerPast.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 30)  // or, better, turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and then define constraints for this subview
            view.addSubview(myRideViewControllerPast.view)
            myRideViewControllerPast.didMove(toParent: self)
            myRideViewControllerPast.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0 - self.view.frame.width, y: 30, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 30)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.myRideViewControllerPast.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 30)
            }, completion:nil)
            myRideViewControllerPast.view.isHidden = true
        } else {
            let segmentItems = ["Request","Upcoming", "Past"]
            segmentControll = UISegmentedControl(items: segmentItems)
            segmentControll.frame = CGRect(x:0 ,y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 30)
            segmentControll.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentControllChanged), for: .valueChanged)
            segmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
            segmentControll.backgroundColor = .rideelyGray
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                segmentControll.selectedSegmentTintColor = .rideelyYellow
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
            view.addSubview(segmentControll)
            requestedRideViewController = (storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RequestedRideViewController") as! RequestedRideViewController)
            addChild(requestedRideViewController)
            requestedRideViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)  // or, better, turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and then define constraints for this subview
            view.addSubview(requestedRideViewController.view)
            requestedRideViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
            requestedRideViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0 - self.view.frame.width, y: 30, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.requestedRideViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 30)
            }, completion:nil)
            requestedRideViewController.view.isHidden = false

            upcomingRideViewController  = (storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UpcomingRideViewController") as! UpcomingRideViewController)
            addChild(upcomingRideViewController)
            upcomingRideViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 30)  // or, better, turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and then define constraints for this subview
            view.addSubview(upcomingRideViewController.view)
            upcomingRideViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
            upcomingRideViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0 - self.view.frame.width, y: 30, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.upcomingRideViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 30)
            }, completion:nil)
            upcomingRideViewController.view.isHidden = true

            myRideViewControllerPast  = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyRideViewController")
            addChild(myRideViewControllerPast)
            myRideViewControllerPast.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 30)  // or, better, turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and then define constraints for this subview
            view.addSubview(myRideViewControllerPast.view)
            myRideViewControllerPast.didMove(toParent: self)
            myRideViewControllerPast.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0 - self.view.frame.width, y: 30, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 30)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.myRideViewControllerPast.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 30)
            }, completion:nil)
            myRideViewControllerPast.view.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    private func openCloseSideMenu() {
        if sideMenuOpen {
            sideMenuOpen = false
            controller.removeFromParent()
            controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        } else {
            sideMenuOpen = true
            addChild(controller)
            controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width * 0.8, height: view.frame.height)  // or, better, turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and then define constraints for this subview
            view.addSubview(controller.view)
            controller.didMove(toParent: self)
            controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0 - self.view.frame.width, y: 0, width: view.frame.width * 0.8, height: view.frame.height)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width * 0.8, height: self.view.frame.height)
            }, completion:nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your api calls in **segmentControllChanged**, there are many ways you can achieve this . One way that will best suit is

You can use flag for each controller to check when the segment is scrolled then only you hit the api explicitly otherwise don't hit it.

**1 example for this**

CODE -

```
switch segmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 1:
                print("segment 1")
                myRideViewControllerUpcoming.isVisible = true
                // call your myRideViewControllerUpcoming api method here 
            }
```